# Amazon RDS Read Replica configuration Postgres database from an spring boot application deployed on PCF?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-rds, cloud-foundry, spring-jdbc, read-replication

Hi All currently we are have deployed our springboot code to pcf which is running on aws.

we are using aws database - where we have cup service and VCAP_SERVICES which hold the parameter of db.

Below our configuration to get datasource

```
 @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            dataSource = connectionFactory().dataSource();
            configureDataSource(dataSource);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
        }

    private void configureDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource tomcatDataSource = asTomcatDatasource(dataSource);
        tomcatDataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        tomcatDataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        tomcatDataSource.setValidationInterval(30000);
        tomcatDataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        tomcatDataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(60000);
        tomcatDataSource.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        tomcatDataSource.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
        tomcatDataSource.setMaxActive(Environment.getAsInt("MAX_ACTIVE_DB_CONNECTIONS", tomcatDataSource.getMaxActive()));
    }

    private org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource asTomcatDatasource(DataSource dataSource) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(dataSource, "There is no DataSource configured");
        DataSource targetDataSource = ((DelegatingDataSource)dataSource).getTargetDataSource();
        return (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) targetDataSource;
    }
```

**Now when we have read replicas created , what configuration do i need to modify so our spring boot application uses the read replicas?**

is Just    @Transactional(readOnly = true) on the get call is enough - that it will be automatically taken care? or do i need to add some more configuration

```
@Repository
public class PostgresSomeRepository implements SomeRepository {
  

    @Autowired
    public PostgresSomeRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, RowMapper<Consent> rowMapper) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        this.rowMapper = rowMapper;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<SomeValue> getSomeGetCall(List<String> userIds, String applicationName, String propositionName, String since, String... types) {
      //Some Logic
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper, paramList.toArray());
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            throw new ErrorGettingConsent(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }  
}
```

**Note:we have not added any spring aws jdbc dependency**

Comment: i have gone through (https://reflectoring.io/spring-cloud-aws-rds/) this link but it is totally different as we are deploying in PCF and using VCAP Service using cloud connecter

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the cloud service name is `my_db`.

1. Map the cloud service to the application config `appication-cloud.yml` used by default in the CF (BTW this is better than using the connector because you can customize the datasource)

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    # my_db
    url: ${vcap.services.my_db.credentials.url} 
    username: ${vcap.services.my_db.credentials.username} 
    password: ${vcap.services.my_db.credentials.password} 
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
      data-source-properties:
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
        useServerPrepStmts: true
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    show-sql: true
```

2. put the service to the application `manifest.yml`:

```yaml
---
applications:
  - name: my-app
    env:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "cloud" # by default
    services:
      - my_db
```